# Rest : Getting children Resources

Tags: rest, restful-url

We have Parent and Child entity.We can do this to get Children Collection resources.

Parent/1/Children

Now, we are thinking of implementing an endpoint where we can send multiple parent Id so that we don't have to hit the same api multiple times. 
Doing this approach,are we breaking Restful principles ?
If not what is the right approach

Parent/1,2,3/Children

Parent/Children?ParentIds = 1,2,3

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion looks awkward to me as sub-resources URL usually apply to one parent resource only.

So why don't create a separate children resource and use query parameter to filter out the parent ? Both following are the common design for supplying a list of value to a query parameter:

```
/children?parentId=1,2,3
/children?parentId=1&parentId=2&parentId=3
```

I like the first one more as it looks simpler , cleaner and more elegant to me.

Comment: I edited to make it less awkward. You mean create a new endpoint entirely and not do the parent/children?parentId =1,2,3